# NULLs Returned from Client Side Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I'm developing a client application that consumes a 3rd party web service (soap) in c#.
The soap responds with multiple 'Suppliers' node. However, the array in c# contains NULL values. 
Basically the variable;

```
SuppliersType[] Suppliers
```

has NULL values in its elements.
The other variables (such as the response code) are populated though.
The Suppliers array should be populated with the  nodes returned by the web service. 
 
I'm using the class that VS generates when you add a service reference. 
I call the class using:

```
ServiceReference2.SuppliersType[] Suppliers;
Client.SupploerProfiles(DTStamp,ID, out ResponseCode, out ResponseMessage, out Suppliers);
```

I have included snippets of the WSDL and the class that VS generates.
 
Any assistance is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
 
The soap response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:tpw="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soapenv:Body>
<tpw:SupplierProfilesResponse>
<DateTimeStamp>2011-01-01 22:22:212</DateTimeStamp>
<ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
<ResponseMessage>Success</ResponseMessage>
<Suppliers>
<SupplierName>A</SupplierName>
<SupplierNumber>5559875421</SupplierNumber>
</Suppliers>
<Suppliers>
<SupplierName>B</SupplierName>
<SupplierNumber>5559875421</SupplierNumber>
</Suppliers>
<Suppliers>
<SupplierName>C</SupplierName>
<SupplierNumber>5559875421</SupplierNumber>
</Suppliers>
</tpw:SupplierProfilesResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The definition of the Suppliers Type in the WSDL

```
<xsd:element name="SupplierProfilesResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="DateTimeStamp" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true">
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ResponseCode" type="xsd:int" nillable="true">
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ResponseMessage" type="xsd:string" nillable="true">
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Suppliers" type="tns:SuppliersType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="7">
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="SuppliersType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="SupplierName" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="SupplierNumber" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"></xsd:element> 
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>   
</wsdl:types>
```

The snippet from the class the VS generates:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.example.com")]
public partial class SuppliersType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string supplierNameField;
private string supplierNumberField;
 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 0)]
public string SupplierName
{
get
{
return this.supplierNameField;
}
set
{
this.supplierNameField = value;
this.RaisePropertyChanged("SupplierName");
}
}
 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 1)]
public string SupplierNumber
{
get
{
return this.supplierNumberField;
}
set
{
this.supplierNumberField = value;
this.RaisePropertyChanged("SupplierNumber");
}
}
 
public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
if ((propertyChanged != null))
{
propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you convinced that the web service is in fact *not* returning null elements in the array?

Comment: When I view the elements in the array, they are all set to null.

Comment: @user1327240 and you expected what exactly?

Comment: The web service responds with SupplierName and SupplierNumber elements in the Suppliers Node. I expect the SupplierName and SupplierNumber values to be stored in the array.

Comment: I think what people are saying is that maybe the server is setting the values to null.  In which case you are getting the correct results.

Comment: What exactly is a client-side web service? Do you mean that you are developing a client and the web service is running on a server somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

I am writing a client application that consumes a 3rd party web service. The web service replies with Supplier data (in the 'Suppliers' Nodes).
However, when c# deserializes the soap reply, the elements in the Supplier array are null, which is shouldn't be. 
The 'Suppliers' array contain the SupplierName and SupplierNumber that the web service responded with.

I found one article that describes a similar problem, however, the solution did not help me. 
The article is located @ [link]http://hans.liss.pp.se/node/702

Comment: I tested the web service using third party tools such as soapUI/eclipse/oxygen XML.
These third party tools are able to read the response correctly.

Comment: Post the WSDL for the service. This sounds like the typical problem with services which are not WS-I BP1 compliant. Specifically, there is a difference of opinion about XML namespaces. You got nulls because no data in the correct namespace was received.

Comment: The WSDL is located at: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/65420529/Untitled3.wsdl

Comment: @JohnSaunders How can I check that the WSDL is WS-I BP 1 compliant. Eclipse only validates the WSDL again WS-I compliance, or is this the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Use a sniffer like Fiddler to see the data that is coming back

You could also use Disco to get the latest WSDL and dependent files from the URL.
Then you could use svcutil to build a proxy class(s) and config segment.
This will aid in error capture and other buffer tweats you might need

Also I cannot see that SuppliersType is an array or a collection.
In the WSDL link it is a complex type with 2 elements SupplierName and SupplierNumber.
Are you sure that you are using the correct method?
try Disco to get all the types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greg.
I have used fiddler to get the response. I posted the response in my query above. 
You are correct, the supplier type is a single complex type. However the 'Suppliers' element uses the 'SuppliersType', which returns 0 or more Suppliers node.  

`<xsd:element name="Suppliers" type="tns:SuppliersType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="7`
Maybe I'm miss understanding how soap/wsdl works.

I will use disco and get back to you.